# Clever way to get equal margins in Sketch app?

Tags: sketch-app, workflow

When I'm designing pages I want certain margins to be the same. To achieve this I currently draw up a rectangle with a height/width of X, and use this to space out the elements equally.

This is an example where I would duplicate a 20px high rectangle to space out all items equally.

[image]

But there has to be a better way, right?

So far I figured I can incorporate a 'padding' in a symbol by making the artboard slightly larger, I'd still use the rectangle once but at least not 100 times. This also doesn't work very well when I need to make for example unordered lists in my design. Not every list item will have the same height, so this trick won't work.

Comment: https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/canvas/rulers-guides-grids/ ? or you mean on loads of individual elements rather than at an artboard level?

Comment: @Chris yes, loads of individual elements. Let's say I need to display how content on a webpage looks and I want to keep the spacing equal for all images on the page, and then for all textboxes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use plugins for that.

More specifically [Sketch Mate](https://github.com/getflourish/sketch-mate), but there are many that can provide you with this functionality:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vAuG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With text you just change the line height to 20px or whatever you like e.g.

[image]

With regards to icons in line with the text you'd need to line them up manually

Comment: Maybe I didn't give the best example in my post. Thanks for the tip, but I use mostly symbols for everything so setting line height won't be an option. Nor is it very useful to my developer as he will code these as list items.

Comment: if he codes them as list items he can set the paragraph height between items